# WebClient filter to transform the response body

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-webflux, spring-webclient

I'm using Spring Declarative HTTP Clients and I'm having a hard time being siloed with WebClient. Seems that it still has very poor documentation and few examples over the internet.

I'm trying to transform the response body with a filter to remove some boilerplate json from it. Here's what I tried:

```
    private ExchangeFilterFunction responseUnwrapper() {
    return ExchangeFilterFunction.ofResponseProcessor(clientResponse -> {
        if (clientResponse.statusCode().is2xxSuccessful()) {
            return clientResponse
                    .bodyToMono(DataDTO.class)
                    .map(DataDTO::data)
                    .flatMap(mappedResponse -> Mono.just(ClientResponse.create(clientResponse.statusCode())
                            .headers(httpResponse -> clientResponse.headers().asHttpHeaders())
                            .body(mappedResponse)
                            .build()));
        } else {
            return Mono.just(clientResponse);
        }
    });
}
```

So basically the server response wraps the body in a `"data": {}` attribute which I'm trying to remove here.
The above code doesn't compile because the body function of `ClientReponse.Builder` expects one of the following:

```
    Builder body(Function<Flux<DataBuffer>, Flux<DataBuffer>> transformer);

    Builder body(Flux<DataBuffer> body);

    Builder body(String body);
```

It is not clear to me how to use those, and if I just do `.body(mappedResponse.toString())` I get an `IllegalStateException: Timeout on blocking read for 5000000000 NANOSECONDS`

So how do I properly transform a response body using WebClient?

EDIT: this is DataDTO code

```
public record DataDTO<T>(T data) {}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to serialize your data into a `String` a pass it to the `Builder body(String body)`. Probably you want to build a json, however technically `mappedResponse.toString()` also fits. Your `IllegalStateException` is not related to that part of code. Looks like you are calling `block()` somewhere on a webclient's response Mono.

By the way, you don't need `flatMap` here, `map` is enough:

```
            ExchangeFilterFunction.ofResponseProcessor(clientResponse -> {
                if (clientResponse.statusCode().is2xxSuccessful()) {
                    return clientResponse
                            .bodyToMono(DataDTO.class)
                            .map(DataDTO::data)
                            .map(dtoData -> ClientResponse.create(clientResponse.statusCode())
                                    .headers(httpResponse -> clientResponse.headers().asHttpHeaders())
                                    .body(dtoData.toString()) // probably Jackson's objectMapper.writeValueAsString()
                                    .build());
                } else {
                    return Mono.just(clientResponse);
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

@gdomo's suggestion worked although I had to make a small change. It seems that the headers don't actually get forwarded to the final response. I was getting the following error

```
Caused by: org.springframework.web.reactive.function.UnsupportedMediaTypeException: Content type 'application/octet-stream' not supported for bodyType=java.util.List<com.xxxx.MyObject> at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.BodyExtractors.readWithMessageReaders(BodyExtractors.java:205)
```

Despite the server response having Content-Type: application/json (confirmed in postman). So I had to manually set the content-type header. Following is the final solution

```
ExchangeFilterFunction.ofResponseProcessor(clientResponse -> {
        if (clientResponse.statusCode().is2xxSuccessful()) {
            return clientResponse
                    .bodyToMono(DataDTO.class)
                    .map(DataDTO::data)
                    .map(data -> ClientResponse.create(clientResponse.statusCode())
                            .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
                            .body(JsonUtils.writeValue(data))
                            .build());
        } else {
            return Mono.just(clientResponse);
        }
    });
```

(JsonUtils.writeValue is a static ObjectMapper).